# DDMS freezes when select a device

Tags: android, ddms

On linux i have an Android ARM emulator running. I wanted to see the log output, so i started ddms on the command line. After ddms opened i selected the device. Then after two or three seconds DDMS freezes. It freezes only after i select the device.

Comment: https://projects.invisionapp.com/share/PG4CO7DRS#/screens/99569016
https://projects.invisionapp.com/share/894H60ZB5#/screens/99264371
https://projects.invisionapp.com/share/V33OKEUNZ#/screens
phase I: http://invis.io/H42A9MQWE
phase II: http://invis.io/QY3KZU6CZ
Version 1 : https://invis.io/M3205UEFR 
Version 2:  https://invis.io/VG4GJTB9H
http://mynewsiteonline.co.uk/design1/mall/design/1/allmockups.php

Answer (score 0):

Its a common issue with ddms. You can try to `adb kill-server`, `adb start-server`. This should work.